# MySQL - Unable to serialize date/time value

Tags: .net, mysql

Hi I am having a weird issue with MySQL right now. I am executing a MySqlCommand of type stored procedure which has some datetime values in it and I have verified that all date time values are correct. But I when I execute this command as cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() it thorws erros as

> **"Fatal error encountered during command execution"**

InnerException -

> **"Unable to serialize date/time value"**

I read in some online forums that it is the issue with .NET connector for MySQL and is resolved in version 6.3.3. Well, I am using version 6.5.4 and still facing issue. When I pass DateTime.Now as a value everything works well but none of the other date value works.

Does anybody know any work around?

Comment: I added `.net` tag, but if it is wrong, please change it.

Comment: @Jocelyn - thanks for your reply. In fact issues was with my stroed proc where one parameters was having incorrect datatype marked as datetime. I was able to resolve issue. Thanks a lot for taking time to reply :)

Comment: @sherebiah.tishbi - I was also saying that the problem is either in the connector or your code, so we need to see more.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well and this was one of those things you can search for forever. I copied the code to add parameters and forgot to change the MySqlDbType to Int32 of that other parameter. Assuming (stupid me) my date variable in C# was incorrect I was looking for the wrong thing.

So check again, if you have this, you're probably passing a non date into a parameter that expects a date.